# What does fgets() do, that strncpy() fails to do here?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am writing a program that does some simple tcp-communication, but I am not too fluent in c/c++.

**My problem**

When I am putting data from **stdin** into a buffer(char array) with `fgets()`, it works fine.

When I am trying to put data from a **string** into the same buffer with `strncpy()`, it *seems* to work as I print out the buffer - but I get problems down the line.

**Working fgets() example:**

```
int messageSize = 256;
char buffer[messageSize];

bzero(buffer, messageSize);
fgets(buffer, messageSize, stdin);
printf("%s\n", buffer); // seems good, prints out whatever I send in stdin

// passing the buffer on, no problems
```

**Failing strncpy() example:**

```
int messageSize = 256;
char buffer[messageSize];

bzero(buffer, messageSize);
strncpy(buffer, mystring.c_str(), messageSize);
printf("%s\n", buffer); // seems good, prints out whatever the string was

// passing the buffer on and I get problems
```

Why do I get problems when using the `strncopy()` code, shouldn't the results be identical if I pass the string in **stdin**?

**The problems i get down the line:**

When passing the buffer on here is what happens:

```
// we just put data into the buffer

n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0)
    error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer, messageSize);
n = read(sockfd, buffer, messageSize);
if (n < 0)
    error("ERROR reading from socket");
```

When using `strncpy()`, the `error()` function never gets called, but the code never gets on from `read()`. When using `fgets()`, everything works fine.

Comment: You are using C++, not C. And that is important, especially since `std::string` can contain a NUL in places other than the end. (Moral: don't double tag).

Comment: What are “problems”? Are you using the same string for each test?

Comment: what's the size of `mystring`? you should use `mystring.size()` instead of `messageSize`. And null-terminate your buffer, since `strncpy` doesn't do that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, `messageSize` (the size of the destination buffer, not the source) is the correct parameter to pass to `strncpy`, and it will null-terminate if `mystring.size() < messageSize`. (Yes, checking for `buffer[255] != '\0'` is a good idea.)

Comment: C++ forbids variable-size array, right?

Comment: OK, `strncpy` protects overflow from input! that's a good choice over memcpy in that case.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes but I think g++ tolerates that.

Comment: @Ryan, yes same string.

Comment: @StoryTeller, right okay. Thank you, I hadn't quite made the distinction there.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, doesn't `strncpy()` null terminate my buffer as well?

Comment: Did you make sure to include newlines if applicable? `fgets` keeps a newline. And again: what are “problems down the line”?

Comment: @Ryan, I did not, but it isn't applicable. I am writing an edit with the problems explained now

Comment: `char buffer[messageSize];` is not allowed in standard C++

Comment: @EmilBonneKristiansen `strncpy` does not terminate the buffer if the input was too long. For this reason it is a bad choice for almost all applications

Comment: This use of `strncpy` will fail in exactly the same cases as `strcpy` would. But it adds the overhead of zeroing the **entire** buffer, while `strcpy` would just add a 0 at the end.